# TSQL results in specific number of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transpose

I'm trying to create a query that will distribute the row results in specific number of columns (ex. 4). See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: the column number is limited to just 4. if the results are more than 4 it should go to the next row of 4 columns.

Answer (score 3):

It is presentation matter and it should be handled on application level.
But if you insist:

```
SELECT column1 = MIN(CASE WHEN grp=1 THEN PartNumber+CHAR(13)+SerialNumber END)
      ,column2 = MIN(CASE WHEN grp=2 THEN PartNumber+CHAR(13)+SerialNumber END)
      ,column3 = MIN(CASE WHEN grp=3 THEN PartNumber+CHAR(13)+SerialNumber END)
      ,column4 = MIN(CASE WHEN grp=4 THEN PartNumber+CHAR(13)+SerialNumber END)
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY rn) AS grp
      FROM (SELECT *,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0)-1)/4 AS rn FROM tab)s)sub
GROUP BY rn;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b31c7991161fd2339fcd5aa2e3e474f9)**